# Can I have multiple client apps in a Blazor App project?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

The new Blazor App template in .NET 8 consists of a server and a client project. Whereas the server project hosts the statically rendered pages like App.razor, the actual application resides in the client project. The question now is if it is possible to host multiple such client projects with one server project and map these depending on the route? We want to have only one instance of the API running. The clients are all different but use the same backend API.

Sure, there could be a separately hosted API project but then the server mode components in the Blazor App would have to do a loopback request (the API is hosted on the same server as the Blazor applications). That means unnecessary data serialization and IO transport.

Comment: You can always create and configure separate Blazor Wasm projects. No need for a server-per-client. Just setup CORS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/multiple-hosted-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=port-domain

Comment: @Taco The article linked unfortunately doesn't work in Blazor .NET 8 any more. It's meant for Blazor .NET 7, any only for WASM scenarios.

Comment: I have the same problem and have opened a new issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52216

Comment: I have not yet updated, but that explains why the page does not have an .NET 8 version.

Comment: @ℍ ℍ The new blazor app leverages both server side rendering and client side rendering at the same time. That is not possible with pure wasm projects. It does need a server for the server side rendering.

Comment: I get `Conflicting assets with the same target path` from `GenerateStaticWebAssetsManifest` target when I try to reference more than 1 client project in Blazor 8 mixed rendering solution